# Modifying query execution plan with Criteria API to force index usage

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, query-optimization

I have a software built with Hibernate 4.3 on top of a Mysql 5.6 database. Within the application, I have implemented certain queries using the Criteria API. I would like to modify the query execution plan by explicitly specifying the index to be used in some of the join clauses. Is there a way to achieve this using the Criteria API, or do I need to rewrite everything using native SQL?

Comment: Just sayin'  Forcing index use almost never is a good way to improve query performance. Make sure you've done EXPLAIN for your ORM's queries and added appropriate indexes before you set out on that trail of tears.

Comment: Your comment is not relevant to the question. Force index is a perfectly fine tool to optimize a query, I did my evaluations and that is what I need.